# How to extract multiple range of values on the same field using cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have set condition in pagination to extract books with price range between 100-300, 800-1000 & 1400-1500 only, but getting only the books of price range 1400-1500.

```
$options = array(
            'limit'=>20,
            'order'=>'RAND()',
            'contain'=>array(
                'Student' => array(
                    'User'
                ),
                'Book'
            )
        );

$options['contain']['Book']['conditions']['OR']['Book.price BETWEEN ? AND ? '] = array(100,300);
$options['contain']['Book']['conditions']['OR']['Book.price BETWEEN ? AND ? '] = array(800,1000);
$options['contain']['Book']['conditions']['OR']['Book.price BETWEEN ? AND ? '] = array(1400,1500);
```

Comment: can you please post the executed query

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Please try below syntax and let me know if any issue.**

```
$options = array(
    'limit' => 20,
    'order' => 'RAND()',
    'contain' => array(
        'Student' => array(
            'User'
        ),
        'Book' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'or' => array(
                    'Book.price BETWEEN ? AND ? ' => array(100, 300),
                    'Book.price BETWEEN ? AND ? ' => array(800, 1000),
                    'Book.price BETWEEN ? AND ? ' => array(1400, 1500)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, In this case also it shows only the results of the last condition.